# Non-parametric statistical upper-tailed test

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric

I have the following sample:

> 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
>     0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000
>     0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.000000000 0.003523818
>     0.014789602 0.014789602 0.034094375 0.049659885 0.055440686 0.061278385
>     0.068911725 0.082682213 0.126288986 0.128287276 0.137266110 0.169542550
>     0.211512094 0.256243626 0.281680013 0.281680013 0.304499345 0.307458564
>     0.307458564 0.307458564 0.310555679 0.315311828 0.323869159 0.328993454
>     0.328993454 0.335356766 0.361119077 0.363122638 0.367470607 0.377125540
>     0.377574315 0.381760810 0.397392385 0.404523677 0.431556515 0.434224159
>     0.436889978 0.440440344 0.441433374 0.457957533 0.472876505 0.511048006
>     0.518766446 0.530426277 0.542021125 0.546258913 0.546258913 0.546258913
>     0.548570696 0.555946551 0.558004199 0.563761824 0.567996204 0.567996204
>     0.575551287 0.577040454 0.587769928 0.592481849 0.592845818 0.592972392
>     0.596972123 0.602246716 0.604892216 0.609423010 0.617436245 0.627695834
>     0.631284888 0.638663442 0.656256980 0.659612888 0.669788704 0.676867349
>     0.683999750 0.687109652 0.696224573 0.712662280 0.720030056 0.720611570
>     0.731200224 0.740205035 0.763246750 0.769669866 0.776154803

and I need a non-parametric statistical upper-tailed test that gives me the pvalue for each observation of the sample, that the observation belongs to the distribution. I can not make the assumption about normality or symmetry.
[image: Histogram]

Comment: If you make no distributional assumptions, then you have absolutely no evidence against them!  It's impossible to produce any kind of p-value in that case.

Comment: I have a sample of the distribution, I would like to know how well an observation fit in the distribution of the sample. I believe some test like z-test could give me this, but I cannot make the assumption of the normality.

Comment: Without an assumption, there is nothing you can say: *by definition* of a sample, each of your values is equally worthy of being part of the sample and no one of them, no matter how extreme it might seem, is any less "unusual" than any other.

Comment: Ok, but if a new example arrives, let suppose a 0.78, how can I know if this new example belongs to the same distribution of the sample or not?

Comment: You cannot.  **You have to make assumptions about the distribution.**

Comment: What kind of assumption should I do in this case?

Comment: Something that would be appropriate for your application.  It's impossible to recommend anything when your question has been phrased abstractly. You have only told us what you *cannot* assume--namely, normality--but you haven't provided any information about what you *can* assume!